# What does this line of code in CRUDOperations.vb do?

Tags: vb.net, sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Here is some code from the CRUDOperations.vb file in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 SDK:

```
  ' Retrieve the account containing several of its attributes.
  Dim cols As New ColumnSet(New String() { "name", "address1_postalcode", "lastusedincampaign" })
  Dim retrievedAccount As Account = CType(_service.Retrieve("account", _accountId, cols), Account)
  Console.Write("retrieved, ")
  ' Update the postal code attribute.
  retrievedAccount.Address1_PostalCode = "98052"
  ' The address 2 postal code was set accidentally, so set it to null.
  retrievedAccount.Address2_PostalCode = Nothing
```

Now if I am understanding correctly, the following line:

```
      Dim retrievedAccount As Account = CType(_service.Retrieve("account", _accountId, cols), Account)
```

Doesn't seem to actually do anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It calls `_service.Retrieve("account", _accountId, cols)`
2. It casts the return value to type `Account`.
3. It stores the return value in the variable `retrievedAccount`.

And then the subsequent lines modify the properties of the account that is referenced by `retrievedAccount`.